# Border definition

Tags: html, excel, sharepoint, border

I wanted to know how the Sharepoint client determines the border definition automatically.

It is my understanding that the xlsx document shares the border between the two cells (so if I have a border between A1 and A2, A1 has a lower border and A2 has an upper border).  However, when I use Sharepoint to convert my xlsx document to html, sometimes I may have the border defined in the div above the line and sometimes in the div below (for example if I have a border between A1,B1 and A2,B2, the div corresponding to A1 has a border-bottom definition and the div corresponding to B2 has a border-top definition and A2 and B1 have no border definition).

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to know this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to be able to add a margin to cells on the side that the border exists so that line weight remains consistent in all browsers. So if my example occurs, it actually makes the lines not match up anymore. I need sharepoint to be consistent on defining the border for an entire row or col, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The top border of one Excel cell occupies the same space as the bottom border (if any) of the cell immediately above but each cell is independent. Simply apply a bottom border to one cell and a top border to another then move the cells around to see that though when adjacent there may be no visible difference the cell retains a record of which border has been applied:

[image: SO25875573 example]

Comment: Okay, so when I test that, I have cells that should not have any upper border, but sharepoint assigns the div that corresponds to that cell and upper border.  Using the same example as before A1 and B1 are supposed to have lower borders while A2 and B2 should have nothing, but when sharepoint creates the divs, the div corresponding to B2 has an upper border and B1 has nothing.